# Sharepoint site collection is blank after db move

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a host name site collection and content database (name: db2) using power shell script in PROD. The site was working as expected. Then I moved the content database from Test env (name: db1) to PROD env (name db2). In test db I had a lot of data which we wanted in PROD. But when we browse the site in PROD it's blank (It's not showing test db data). Any reason why test data is not showing in PROD? Are we missing any steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following things.

When you moved the content database from one environment to another, did you change the owner of the database in the new environment, as most people design the database access account of the prod environment will be different which may not have access to the database from test environment. Change the owner of the database to solve this.

The other problem maybe you didnt replace the database you just restored it with the same name. The solution for this will be replacing the database using the backup from the test environment.